# ¿Cómo cambiar las texturas de elementos duplicados por separado en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un cubo de un tamaño específico, lo he duplicado varias veces y necesito poner una textura diferente a cada uno, pero al cambiar las propiedades de un cubo se cambia en todos.

¿Dónde puedo separar y decir que actúen como objetos independientes?

Comment: ¿Desde el inspector o desde código?